# Can we deploy Splash on Aws Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, scrapy, aws-lambda, splash-js-render

I am writing a scraping app which is running on Lambda. I want to combine Scrapy with Splash, but I am not sure that can Splash run on lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you are trying to install `Splash`.

1. If you want to run it using `docker` image, then take a look at [Elastic container service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/Welcome.html). Lambda is not ideal for running containerized app.
2. If you are going to run it by manual way, like mentioned [here](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) you can do so. But as per the doc, its not recommended. As `AWS Lambda` supports `Python`, this should not be problem, as long as it doesn't require any other dependency. Also consider the starting time for your `Splash` server. Lambda allocates instances on the fly, So it might take time to start your application (`AWS lambda` cold start).

Comment: I think this answer is outdated, AWS Lambda now supports Docker images: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html

Not sure what "not ideal" refers to exactly, and if that concern is still applicable.

Answer (score 0):

- I think its worth having a look at lambda runtime API and lambda layers. [aws docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-use-any-programming-language-and-share-common-components/)